# Is there any library for T-SQL to turn it object oriented?

Tags: sql, t-sql, oop

Microsoft Ajax Library has added full object orientation to JavaScript. Is there any library, framework, component, package, etc equivalent for T-SQL? It would be very nice to write object oriented SQL scripts in MS SQL Server.

Cheers,
afsharm

Comment: Are you sure that would be nice?

Comment: Yes! I'm used to write in C# and if It would be helpful to migrate my object-oriented skills to T-SQL. It will increase my performance.

Comment: To be effective in writing code for SQL server you need to ditch the object-orientation and think interms of sets of data. Object oriented coding is actively harmful to database performance. Learn t-sql properly instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server, like other RDBMSs, doesn't come in an object flavor. Sorry.

These days this problem is solved on the application end through the use of ORM (object-relational mapping) frameworks. Options depend on what development platform you're using. For .NET, take a look at Microsoft's Entity Framework and SubSonic.

Answer (score 1):

Closest thing I can think of is [SQL CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345136(SQL.90).aspx).

Otherwise there is no OO scripting support in MSSQL.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ  - kind of...

Comment: But, I'm going to use just SQL Server not VS or csc.exe or any compilations.